# How to save an HTML page from a web site using Chrome

Tags: chrome-for-android, downloading, html

I have a web site that has some simple HTML pages with no images, no external CSS or JavaScript references. So the whole HTML page is a single self-containing file that has HTML code, together with *inline* CSS and JavaScript code. In other words, once I copy the HTML file into my `Downloads` folder on my mobile device, I can use it (while being ***offline***) by loading the following into the Chrome browser:

`file:///storage/emulated/0/Download/my_page.html`

The problem is that I cannot download the web page from my web site into the `Downloads` folder using Chrome on my mobile device: When I go to:

`https://my-site.tld/xxx/my_page.html`

and display the page in the mobile browser, I can use the download (⭳) button on Chrome browser's tab; however it creates an `.mthml` file instead, with a name like this:

`Title of My Page.mhtml`

When I try to open this file while my mobile device is offline, none of the interactive content on the page (e.g., buttons, input boxes, etc.) is enabled. Note that my page contains interactive content that is processed ***locally*** by JavaScript contained in the page.

Currently, the only solution is to connect my mobile device to my PC (using USB for example) and copy the `.html` file from my PC to the mobile's `Downloads` file. Once I copy the `.html` file and open it on my mobile device using the `file:///...` URL as given above, the page's JavaScript works as expected (contrary to the `.mhtml` version).

Assuming that the `.html` page on `my-site` is updated frequently, it is tedious to download it to PC and copy over my mobile phone when I need an update. There must be a more direct way.

Answer (score 3):

The simplest thing I can think of is to open the file you want to save as source code, which you can do from Chrome Android by prepending `view-source` to the URL, like so.

```
view-source:https://my-site.tld/xxx/my_page.html
```

You can then either copy and paste this code into a local file, or use the share button to open it with a compatible app of your choosing.

If this seems like too much of a pain, you might consider doing something like using PHP to determine whether the file should be viewed or downloaded. For example if the IP address of the request matches your phone, download instead of displaying the file.

```
<?php
/**
 * File url: https://my-site.tld/xxx/my_page.php
 *
 */

$remote_address = filter_input(INPUT_SERVER, 'REMOTE_ADDR', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);

if ($remote_address === '56.57.58.59') {
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"filename.html\"\n");
    header("Content-Type: text/html\n");
}

?>
<!-- Begin actual page content -->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    ....
```

Conversely, you could also simply create a separate page to allow a download regardless of the requesting IP address.

```
<?php
/**
 * File url: https://my-site.tld/xxx/my_page-download.php
 *
 */

header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"filename.html\"\n");
header("Content-Type: text/html\n");
readfile('path/to/file');
```

Additional information about the `Content-Disposition` header may be found in the [Mozilla Developer Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Disposition). It's not the only resource, of course, it's just my personal favorite.

Comment: Thanks Jose. The view-source, select all, copy and paste (into Total Commander's editor) method is an improvement for me...

Comment: My pleasure, glad to hear I could be of some help

Comment: Please note: I upvoted this answer. But, it is not an accepted answer for me, because I am seeking for an answer on how to save an HTML file onto the file system by using  ***only Chrome*** and not any other additional tool.

Comment: It won't work if the page is a few hundred lines.

Comment: **View source** shows the raw HTML that's coming from the server and not the _interpreted_ rendered version of the page. If the page is heavy on js then the difference can be significant.

Comment: Good to know but as others have noticed, copying only works on small sources. And "You can then [...] use the share button to open it with a compatible app": the share button simply forwards the URL with the `view-source:` prefix, so there was no point opening it in Chrome - this alternative basically says don't use Chrome but some other program.